# Does not pass on DeliveryReport action delegate kafka producer .net

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I'm trying log the delivery report when i produce message request to topic on Kafka.
This is my producer:

```
public async Task SendAsync(string message, string topic)
{
    try
    {
        using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(_producerConfig).Build())
        {
            producer.Produce(topic, new Message<Null, string> { Value = message }, handler);
            producer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Delivery failed producer: {e.Message}");
        throw new Exception($"Delivery failed:  {e.Message}", e);
    }
}
```

And then the Action DeliveryReport where i put my _logger to retain some informations

```
Action<DeliveryReport<Null, string>> handler = r => {
    if (r.Error.IsError)
    {
        _logger?.LogError($"Delivery failed: {r?.Error?.Reason}");
        throw new Exception($"Delivery failed:  {r?.Error?.Reason}");
    }

    _logger?.LogInformation($"Status Kafka Message {r?.Status} | " +
        $"Delivery message to topic {r?.Topic} with success: {r?.Message?.Value}");
};
```

The logger's point above are not reached.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Thank you very much.

I tried to configure, remove the flush method but nothing happened.